# Не удается скомпилировать модуль командой make (Armbian)

Tags: linux, makefile, armbian-linux

Не получается скомпилировать из исходника драйвер для тачскрина

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.62-sunxi/build M=/home/nero/ads7846 modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.19.62-sunxi/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

гуглил, но не нашел решения проблемы, да и к тому же далек от темы

Comment: Проверьте наличие папки  `/lib/modules/4.19.62-sunxi/build`. Если такой нет, то создайте.

Comment: создал папку, теперь не видит правил для цели modules

Comment: я так понял нужно поставить linux headers, но система брыкается root@orangepione:/home/nero/development/armbian/build# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.62-sunxi
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.19.62-sunxi'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.19.62-sunxi'